# How to disable insertion between several items in recyclerView while drag-n-drop

Tags: android-recyclerview

I want to create a RecyclerView in which, when dragging elements, I will not be able to insert the element in some positions (for example, as shown in the picture, I will not be able to insert the "math" element between the IT and policy elements, as shown the red arrow, but I will be able to move between the two remaining "policy" elements, as shown by the green arrow). I want those elements between which insertion is prohibited to not be able to move apart when the dragged element passes between them

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Arwxh.png)

I tried a lot of things but nothing works. Now I have made a simple recycler view by java in which dragging is possible, but I can't prevent the insertion between some elements. I don't want to prevent dragging on some elements, I want to prevent insertion between some elements when an another element is dragging

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.